# Magento 2 - Assign product to category by SQL with CSV

Tags: sql, csv, magento2

We have over 110'000 products (4400 config products) and we  need to assign all of them to few categories. Yesterday we run a script but will take a lot of time (20h = only 4000 products).

I think the best option will be to do it directly in sql.

We have a csv with:
SKU of config product | root category | subcategory

I found some information the best will be create table in sql based on the csv but what later?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your question does not have enough information for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can speculate a bit on what you want.  You need to load the CSV file into a table.  Let's call that `staging`.

That table should have an index on `product`.

Then you can do the update with a `join`:

```
update products p join
       staging s
       on p.product = s.product
    set p.category = s.category;
```

You can set two values in the `update` if you need -- your data and your explanation on not consistent on what you actually want to set.

Updating all the rows in a table does take time.  But for 110k products, this should be a few minutes, not hours.

Comment: Thanks for your message. How about the other tables for example with urls? I worry if I will just update as you showed I will destroy other tables.

Comment: @LukaszWozniak . . . This only changes the values in `products`, so I'm not sure what you mean by "destroy other tables".

Comment: Actually my dev found other solution but take a lot of time. First we create the attribute (based of the product name) and then based of attribute we move products to the right category.